# Docker network show DNS entries

Tags: docker, dns

I'm trying to debug a container dns resolving issue on ubuntu linux docker. As described here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services docker usage a embedded DNS server inside container. Are there any commands that list Docker’s embedded DNS server entries ? ( like entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`)
I have tried `docker inspect` and `docker network inspect`.
Also tried starting `dockerd` is debug mode but have not found anything useful.

It does show some config file read like below.

```
INFO[2020-07-13T14:39:58.517777580+05:45] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

But I wanted to list the runtime dns entries of `dockerd` network with dns addresss `127.0.0.11`. Is it possible ?

Comment: The Docker documentation refers to an "embedded" DNS server, which is in the Docker engine, not a container, correct?

Answer (score 13):

It is possible, but you have to parse the JSON printed by `docker network inspect`.

Run `docker network ls` to get the running networks names, and then `docker network inspect NETWORK_NAME` to see the containers in it.

Look for the "Containers" keyword in the JSON, it is a list of connected devices. Look for the instance with the `"IPv4Address": "127.0.0.11/24"` entry, the "Name" key is the DNS name.

I.E. `countly_countly-endpoint` is the DNS name that resolves to ip `10.0.8.4/24`:

```
           "lb-countly_countly": {
                "Name": "countly_countly-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "9f7abf354b5fbeed0be6483b53516641f6c6bbd37ab991544423f5aeb8bdb771",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:08:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.8.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

Note that `countly_` is the network namespace that matches the network name in `docker network ls`, that way you can be sure that they are unique and configure your services to talk to each other using the DNS name according to the rule of `NETWORK-NAME_SERVICE-NAME`.